# In Rails, how to disable textarea and sumbit button at the same time after clicking submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form which contains a textarea and a submit button. When user clicks the submit button, the form will be submitted acyshornizedly using AJAX. I want to disable both the textarea and the button during the submitting.

I tried binding a JS click event to the submit button and disable these two controls there. My code here:

Form:

```
<%= form_for @tweet, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
    <% if @tweet.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%=pluralize(@tweet.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article form being saved:</h2>
            <ul>
                <% @tweet.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="div_add_text">
        <%= f.text_area :content, id: "textarea_add_tweet" %>
        <%= f.submit class: "pure-button", id: "btn_add_tweet" %>
    </div>

    <div class="div_submit">
    </div>
<% end %>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("#btn_add_tweet").click(function() {
        $(this).prop("disabled",true);
        $("#textarea_add_tweet").prop("disabled",true);
    });
});
```

How ever, if i do this, the form would not be submitted. How can I achieve the effect as I want?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting a timeout? OnClick gets called before the button's associated action is executed, so disabling asynchronously should work.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $("#btn_add_tweet").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#btn_add_tweet").prop("disabled",true);
      $("#textarea_add_tweet").prop("disabled",true);
    }, 5);
  };
};
```

Where 5 is the time in milliseconds before the function gets called.

Comment: Hi Kolja, this does work! Thank you so much. One more question, right now I'm disabling this two controls in a js file, say tweet.js. And after saving the newly created tweet, I'll re-enable them in a create.js.erb file, just as rails apps usually do. It seems a little awkward to disable controls at one place and re-enable them at another place. Do you know a better solution for that, while still using rails' remote:true feature?

Comment: This is a little more broad question I think, with multiple good answers. One think I would propose off the top of my head would be grouping the controls to be disabled in a `div` with a class `.disableable` or something, and having two functions that disable/enable all form elements in those, and using those in your timeout. Of course this has problems if you need to have multiple disableables on your page that belong to different forms. In that case you should probably think of a way to share some information (element IDs) across your JS files, and use that to to disable the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use this:

```
$(window).submit(function() { $('#btn_add_tweet, #textarea_add_tweet').attr('disabled', true); });
```

Because if you have added some kind of validation and some how validation fails then it will disable these two things.